# Combining the intersecting results from two mySQL queries

Tags: mysql

So I am trying to get to the final result of the Makers that produce two different Desktop or Laptop Models with RAM of at least 512. I have written two separate MySQL queries that I'm plugging into phpMyAdmin SQL, one that lists the makers that have RAM of at least 512, and another one that only shows the makers that have two laptops or desktops. I don't know if I'm going about it the correct way, but in the end, I want some way to only show the makers that line up with both of them.

Here's the code that I have tried to put together using `JOIN` but it doesn't work.

```
WHERE Product.Type = 'Desktop'
GROUP BY Maker
HAVING count(*) = 2)
UNION
(SELECT Maker FROM Product
WHERE Product.Type = 'Laptop'
GROUP BY Maker
HAVING count(*) = 2))
JOIN
((SELECT Model, Maker, Type
FROM Product NATURAL JOIN Desktop
WHERE Ram >= 512)
UNION
(SELECT Model, Maker, Type
FROM Product NATURAL JOIN Laptop
WHERE Ram >= 512))
```

Here's the example of the database.
Desktop:

[image: Desktop]

Then Laptop:

[image: Laptop]

And Product:

[image: Product]

An example of an answer would then be Makers C and G.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a possible solution.

```
WHERE Desktop.Ram >= 512 AND Maker IN (
    SELECT Maker FROM Product
    WHERE Product.Type = 'Desktop'
    GROUP BY Maker
    HAVING count(*) = 2
    )
UNION
SELECT Maker FROM Product NATURAL JOIN Laptop
WHERE Laptop.Ram >= 512 AND Maker IN (
    SELECT Maker FROM Product
    WHERE Product.Type = 'Laptop'
    GROUP BY Maker
    HAVING count(*) = 2
    );
```

This actually give the answer B, C, and G, but that is also technically correct depending on how you read the question.